# Constructor call of class holding a RAII class causes segmentation fault

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, segmentation-fault, raii

I'm new and I'm learning c++ and a bit of the SFML.
To test what my studies I started consulting the "SFML game development" book, from which I got the ResourceHolder in the code.

The problem is that when I try to implement it the code does compile just fine, but it doesn't execute. After many hours of test and various problems I've arrived to the point where I think (*Hope*) lays the last error.

The problem should be the initialization of the first class, that doesn't initialize because the ResourceHolder that is contained causes problems.

main.cpp

```
#include "Game.h"

int main(){    
    std::cout << "enter main" << std::endl;`
    Game game;
    std::cout << "after initialization" << std::endl;
}
```

Game.h

```
#include "ResourceHolder.h
    
class Game {
public:
    typedef ResourceHolder<sf::Texture, ID> TextureHolder;
    Game();
        
private:
    ResourceHolder<sf::Texture, ID> media;        
};
```

Game.cpp

```
#include "Game.h"

Game::Game()
{
    std::cout << "initializing game" << std::endl;
}
```

ResourceHolder.h

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <cassert>
#include <sfml/Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>

enum class ID {
    Background,
    Player,
    MAX_ENUM,
};

template <typename Resource, typename Identifier>
class ResourceHolder {
public:
    typedef ResourceHolder<sf::Texture, ID> TextureHolder;
    ResourceHolder()
    {
        TextureHolder texture; //todo <--My guess is here starts the trouble

        std::cout << "here" << std::endl;
        texture.load(ID::Background, "Media/Image1.png");
        texture.load(ID::Player, "Media/Image2.png");

    }

    void load(Identifier id, const std::string& filename);
    Resource& get(Identifier id);
    const Resource& get(Identifier id) const;

private:
    std::map<ID, std::unique_ptr<sf::Texture>> mResourceMap; 
    //The IDE flags this as non-used ^^^
};

#include "ResourceHolder.inl"
```

ResourceHolder.inl

```
template <typename Resource, typename Identifier>
void ResourceHolder<Resource, Identifier>::load(Identifier id, const std::string& filename)
{
    std::unique_ptr<sf::Texture> resource(new Resource());
    if (!resource->loadFromFile(filename))
        throw std::runtime_error("ResourceHolder::load -Failed to load " + filename);
    auto inserted = mResourceMap.insert(std::make_pair(id, std::move(resource)));
    assert(inserted.second);
}


template <typename Resource, typename Identifier>
 Resource& ResourceHolder<Resource, Identifier>::get(Identifier id)
{
    auto found = mResourceMap.find(id);
    assert(found != mResourceMap.end());
    return *found->second;
}


template <typename Resource, typename Identifier>
const Resource& ResourceHolder<Resource, Identifier>::get(Identifier id) const
{
    auto found = mResourceMap.find(id);
    assert(found != mResourceMap.end());

    return *found->second;
}
```

Thanks in advance! And please, tell me if I can improve the question in any way, I am scared this could be too verbose even as though I stripped all non necessary functions and variables.

Comment: You are getting infinite recursion, you do not need to create local object inside ctor

Comment: IT WORKS, thank you so much! You have no idea how much I love you right now. And you have been hella fast too <3.